# How to Bind dataIndex to Select All check box

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am trying to bind checkbox field to gird with select all options -

> ```
>  xtype: 'grid',
>  store: {
>         type: 'webapi',
>         api: {
>             read: 'api/Report/GetIfo'
>         },
>         autoLoad: true,
>     },
>  columns: [    
>         { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'first_name'}
>     ], 
>     selModel: {
>                 selType: 'checkboxmodel',    
>                 //dataIndex:'flag',
>                 //showHeaderCheckbox: true
>             }
> ```

I am trying to bind the dataIndex to it so that when grid is loaded, respective checkbox will be selected.

I tried by using

> ```
> selModel: {
>                 selType: 'checkboxmodel',    
>                 //dataIndex:'flag',
>                 //showHeaderCheckbox: true
>             }
> ```

But no success. Please suggest me on how to bind the dataIndex here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion to you is use https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Check

Flag have to  true or false if not, you should convert in your model like

```
{ name: 'flag', type: 'bool',
        convert: function (v) {
            return (v === "True" || v === true) ? true : false;
        }
    }
```