# Select all checkbox on column header click

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am trying to select all the checkbox on header click

Here is my code

> ```
> columns: [
>         { header: 'Select All', xtype: 'checkcolumn' dataIndex: 'active' },
>         { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
>         { header: 'City', dataIndex: 'city' }            
>     ],
>     listeners: {                                                   
>                 'headerclick': {
>                     fn: function (grid, col, e) {
>                         if (col.fullColumnIndex == 0) {
>                             //select row and check checkbox                           
>                     }
>                 },
>                     scope: this
>                 }
>             }
> ```

I am able to get the selected column index. So if it is Zero then i want to go through the rows and check all the checkbox.

How to implement this ? please suggest me.

Comment: Maybe you just need checkbox selection model? http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#grid-plugins

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074408/how-to-bind-dataindex-to-select-all-check-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work out for you. Just need to update your store's records.

```
columns: [
        { header: 'Select All', xtype: 'checkcolumn' dataIndex: 'active' },
        { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { header: 'City', dataIndex: 'city' }            
    ],
    listeners: {                                                   
                'headerclick': {
                    fn: function (grid, col, e) {
                        if (col.fullColumnIndex == 0) {
                            grid.store.each(function(rec){
                                rec.set(col.dataIndex, true);
                            });                          
                    }
                },
                    scope: this
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example to select all columns of click header.

```
columns: [  
    { header: 'Select All', xtype: 'checkcolumn' dataIndex: 'active' },  
    { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },  
    { header: 'City', dataIndex: 'city' }            
],

selModel:{   
      checkOnly : true,   
      mode:'MULTI'  
},
selType: 'checkboxmodel',
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an example to select all column checkbox by check header checkbox, but the position is under the text, I don not find a solution.

```
{
    columns: [
        {
            header: 'Select All',
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            HeaderCheckbox: true,
            dataIndex: 'active'
        },
        {
            header: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name'
        },
        {
            header: 'City',
            dataIndex: 'city'
        }
    ],
    selModel: 'checkboxmodel'
}
```